# Odoo 8 - an Odoo client JavaScript error when trying to display workflow diagram

Tags: workflow, odoo, odoo-8

I am using Odoo 8 on Ubunutu. When trying to display diagram view for a particular workflow (example Settings->Workflows->Workflows->account.invoice.basic) I am getting an error message:

```
Odoo Client Error
TypeError: viewclass is not a constructor
http://127.0.0.1:8069/web/js/web.assets_backend/280e51f:3141
```

[image]

or this error when in Debug mode:

[image]

and the diagram is not displayed.

This is the code snipped from views.js and line 699 is where "new viewclass(...)" is.

```
do_create_view: function(view_type) {
        // Lazy loading of views
        var self = this;
        var view = this.views[view_type];
        var viewclass = this.registry.get_object(view_type);
        var options = _.clone(view.options);
        if (view_type === "form" && this.action && (this.action.target == 'new' || this.action.target == 'inline')) {
            options.initial_mode = 'edit';
        }
'line 699   var controller = new viewclass(this, this.dataset, view.view_id, options);
```

I am also getting the same error when trying to see Calendar View, Graph View, Gantt View in Manufacturing->Manufacturing Orders.

Debugging view.js reveals that "this.registry.get_object(view_type)" is returning NULL for view_type='diagram' making viewclass = NULL.

What causes this error and how I can eliminate it?

Comment: Hello Mr. Nash, can you put your code please? So i give you proper solution.

Answer (score 0):

Use your odoo code from standard source, Like https://github.com/odoo/odoo.git